# aurelia get position on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, position, aurelia

how can i get a position of an element on resize in aurelia. I have a menu with element and on resize elements which overflow the block must be pushed to the dropdown menu. I can make it with jquery and positions of elements but maybe i can make it without it in aurelia. And how can i use jquery properly in the aurelia class. Thanks and sorry for my english :)

```
import $ from 'jquery';



export class CategoriesElement {
    check(){
       // this.dropdown = this.categories;
       $('.categories-menu');
    }
}
```

I cant get the dom element with jquery in the method. I imported jquery but it's doesn't worked properly

Comment: it looks like you're importing jquery correctly, make sure that you've installed it with npm. I'd really recommend avoiding it's use with regards to the DOM within Aurelia though.

Comment: to get the position of an element you can look at its DOM properties like offsetLeft and offsetTop, or you can query the current position with [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use jQuery to get the element. Just use the `ref` custom attribute and the element will become a property on your VM.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=39ed84ccdeab0d064038e201d58f8098**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <h1>Please open your console</h1>
  <div ref="theDiv">${message}</div>

  <button click.delegate="doStuff()">Click Me</button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  message = "Hello";
  doStuff() {
    console.log(this.theDiv.textContent);
  }
}
```